# MYSQL no permite entrar al motor

Tags: mysql, linux, ubuntu

tengo instalado mysql en ubuntu pero cuando quiero ingresar a las bases de datos con el comando:

```
sudo mysql -u root -p
```

No me permite entrar, me aparece el siguiente error:

```
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
```

Comment: duda si estas ingresando la contraseña después de dar enter a ese comando?

Comment: No he establecido ninguna contraseña, lo acabo de instalar y no me solicitó que creara una.

Comment: entonces mete el comando solamente asi mysql -u root

Comment: es decir no pases la bandera -p por que entonces asume que debes indicar una contraseña

Comment: Me sigue apareciendo el mismo mensaje, **Access denied...**

Comment: Es tal cual como dice @AlfredoPaz. No necesitas colocar -p en tu comando ya que no has seteado ninguna clave al usuario. Te recomendaría por cierto que lo hagas ya que "root" es el superusuario de mysql y no es conveniente mantenerlo sin contraseña salvo el estricto fin de testeo.

Comment: añade que versión de mysql usas

Comment: Versión: mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.7.22, for Linux (x86_64) using  EditLine wrapper

Comment: en que sistema operativo estas trabajando?

Comment: ubuntu 18.04 LTS 64 bits

Comment: te mejoraré la respuesta dame 3 minutos espero te sirva

Answer (score 2):

Para el caso que planteas entonces debes, trabajar con el comando de la siguiente manera:

```
mysql -u root
```

> Es decir omite la bandera -p por que entonces si te va a exigir dicho
>   valor; lo que puedes hacer es que una vez dentro hagas un nuevo
>   usuario y le indiques si va a tener contraseña, que privilegios y a
>   que bases de datos va a tener acceso

ACTUALIZACIÓN

Detén el servicio de mysql primero

```
mysql service stop
```

Posterior vigila que dicho proceso si se paró

```
mysql service status
```

Si todo marcha bien entonces haz el siguiente comando

```
mysqld_safe
```

Finalmnete vamos a resetear la contraseña así

Abre otra terminal y escribe lo siguiente

```
mysqld_safe
```

Para el comando anterior aquí tienes mas [información](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysqld-safe.html)

```
ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'MyNewPass';
```

> Donde MyNewPass es la nueva contraseña, te recomiendo para salir del
>   apuro agrega password como contraseña

Aquí mas información sobre cambiar la contraseña

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/resetting-permissions.html

Comment: Cuando trato de ingresar el comando
**mysqld_Safe**
Aparece lo siguiente:

**2018-06-04T22:42:49.386998Z mysqld_safe Logging to syslog.

2018-06-04T22:42:49.391295Z mysqld_safe Logging to '/var/log/mysql/error.log'.

2018-06-04T22:42:49.395964Z mysqld_safe Directory '/var/run/mysqld' for UNIX socket file don't exists.
**

Answer (score 2):

Si no funciona lo que ha colocado el colega @AlfredoPaz en su respuesta podrías intentar lo siguiente:

1) Dirigirse a /etc y editar el archivo my.cnf (/etc/my.cnf)
- Luego debajo de la linea mysqld colocar:

```
skip-grant-tables-under
```

2) Reiniciar el servicio de MySQL con el comando asociado a tu distro de Linux.

3) Intenta ingresar nuevamente en MySQL mediante el comando:

```
mysql -u root
```

4) Coloca una nueva contraseña ejecutando:

```
ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'NewPassword';
```

Donde 'ContraseñaAquí' es la contraseña que deseas colocar para tu usuario root.

5) Luego ejecutas:

flush privileges;

6) Retornas al archivo de un principio y lo editas (/etc/my.cnf) para eliminar lo que habías agregado antes, es decir:

```
skip-grant-tables
```

7) Reinicias nuevamente MySQL con el comando asociado a tu distro de linux

8) Intentas nuevamente:

mysql -u root

Ya a estas alturas deberías poder ingresar sin problemas.

Tuve un problema similar al tuyo y logré resolverlo de esta forma guiandome de la solución aportada por un usuario de StackOverflow habla inglesa, especificamente el usuario se llama @KishoreVenkataramanan. Su solución me funcionó a la perfección. He traducido su solución al español para que tu y otros usuarios de SOes les sea igual de útil que a los usuarios de SO.

Si deseas ver su respuesta puedes ingresar a [MySQL Error: : 'Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41645309/mysql-error-access-denied-for-user-rootlocalhost)

Espero sea de ayuda. Un Saludo!

Comment: gracias por que creo que mi respuesta no le fue útil

Comment: @AlfredoPaz Aún cuando posiblemente no le fue útil al OP considero que es muy útil para la comunidad y es por ello que la he puntuado con +1 ya que igualmente el OP tenia el error de -p en su comando. Un saludo y gracias a ti por valorar mi esfuerzo!